# Logical and operator in Xpath to select values

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have some generated XML like so

```
<resource id="1759" key="8f0ab89b:fb7b:45aa:8863:5c8cf4692194" parentID="1701" level="3" creatorID="0" sortOrder="5" createDate="2018:03:28T13:59:22" updateDate="2018:04:17T15:06:25" nodeName="facebook" urlName="facebook" path=":1,1378,1701,1759" isDoc="" nodeType="1705" creatorName="Scott" writerName="Scott" writerID="0" template="0" nodeTypeAlias="resource">
<resourceImage>{
"focalPoint": {
"left": 0.5,
"top": 0.5
},
"src": "/media/9566/ddd:col_116588_020117_1999x614.jpg",
"crops": [
{
  "alias": "Resource",
  "width": 320,
  "height": 238
}
]
}</resourceImage>
      <categories>Case Studies</categories>
    <resourceLink>http://facebook.com</resourceLink>
    <topic>Admissions</topic>
  </resource>
```

Im trying to use an Xpath Expression to select it by both the topic and category like

```
//* [@id=1701]//*[@isDoc]/ topic[text()[contains(.,'Admissions')]] and category[text()[contains(.,'Webinar')]] /..
```

however I get no match. I am able to make it work by just using one of the parameters like

```
  //* [@id=1701]//*[@isDoc]/ topic[text()[contains(.,'Admissions')]]/..
```

however I do need to be able to filter by both parameters. How am i do doing the logical operator wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the conditions into one predicate and then `and` them. I changed `@id` to `parentID` to match the number. Otherwise it wouldn't have matches the sample data.

The XPath matching the four conditions could be:

```
//*[@parentID='1701' and @isDoc and contains(topic/text(),'Admissions') and contains(categories/text(),'Case Studies')]
```